# Retrieve data using ajax from php

Tags: php, mysql, json, jquery

I have an ajax code which passes data to php and then retrieves data from php...

```
function updateDatabase(syncData){
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            async: false,
            url : 'php/syncData.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {myData : syncData}, //i even used this "mydata"+syncData
            success : function(result){
                res = result;                               
            },
            error : function() {
                res = false;
            }
    });

    return res;
}
```

And here's my php code...

```
<?php

    include("database.php");

    if(isset($_GET['myData'])){
        $data = $_GET['myData'];

        $insert = "INSERT INTO `mydata` VALUES (NULL,'$data')";
        mysql_query($insert);


       $data = mysql_insert_id();
       echo json_encode($data);

}

?>
```

Here's javascript function that pass/calls ajax...

```
<script>

var theData = "blahblah";
var alertData = updateDatabase(theData);

alert(alertData);

</script>
```

the problem is that when i use htmt/text as data type it alerts empty/blank output, but when i used json as data type it alerts false where i conclude it went to error function not to success... anyone knows what's the proper way to do this? or maybe i'm just missing something? Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the ajax response using firebug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're posting the data using jQuery, but you're looking for a `$_GET` value in the PHP. Fix that and see if it changes anything.

**Edit**: It should look like this:

```
...
    if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
        $data = $_POST['myData'];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set content type in your PHP file:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
```

Then echo your data:

```
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Then exit script:

```
exit;
```

Hope it helps!